# How to use IPC (C++ based) on iOS Extension App?

Tags: c++, ios

I am currently implementing an iOS App using QT. Although it is a QT-generated Project,
it is very similar to iOS.

I added the Extension App to Main App and I would like to use IPC without pure iOS function.
So, I want to use shared momory or named pipeline (C++ based).

But I lack knowledge of ios. So I don't know sandboxed path of Extension App.
Which path should I create a pipe line at (using mkfifo function)??

I attached the information about my extension app as a screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I9g0.png)

- I tried to create a pipe line in relative path, but it failed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnP8q.png)

Comment: please add the actual code rather than a screen shot.

Comment: I solved this by just adding /tmp before the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /tmp path only worked on the simulator. In order to operate on the device, after adding the App Group, it took the App Group path and created a pipe line in that path, and it worked correctly